# Inserting json in Mysql from python json dump

Tags: python, mysql, json

I cant insert this query into mysql.  I did a json.dump().  I tried text and blob.  I tried opening and closing quotes.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (campaign_object) 
VALUES ( {"cpa_type": "null", "device_tablets": "True",
 "language": "all", "end_date": null, "bid": "1", "budget": "1", "goal_type": "ctr",
 "frequency": "null", "location": "all", "device_mobile": "True", "device_desktop": 
"True", "impressions": "null", "campaign_name": "1", "start_date": "2012-09-14", 
"insert_date": "2012-09-13 23:00:1347548413"})
```

So...I would have to imagine that MyhSQL can handle json.  I really do want want to pickle.

Comment: I'm not sure that `json.dumps` is necessarily supposed to work when directly interpolated into an `INSERT` statement.  What makes you think this is safe?

Comment: Please include the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use parameterized queries.

```
value = '''{"cpa_type": "null", "...0:1347548413"}'''
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (campaign_object) VALUES (%s)", (value,))
```

This way you avoid needing to escape your json, and you're safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Using a paramaterized query is great advice for how to handle SQL invocation from the application side. My answer considered only the SQL syntax itself, but we can infer that the OP is using SQL in a Python context.

Comment: Indeed, his question is pretty ambiguous in this regard.  Only the json.dump() and tags let us guess :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by handle.

MySQL does not understand JSON as a datatype. But you can store a JSON expression as a string.

I'm assuming that the column `campaign_object` is declared as a character string something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  campaign_object NVARCHAR(8000)
);
```

In which case, you would have to enclose the entire JSON string in a single quotes, like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (campaign_object) 
VALUES ( '{"cpa_type": "null", "device_tablets": "True",
 "language": "all", "end_date": null, "bid": "1", "budget": "1", "goal_type": "ctr",
 "frequency": "null", "location": "all", "device_mobile": "True", "device_desktop": 
"True", "impressions": "null", "campaign_name": "1", "start_date": "2012-09-14", 
"insert_date": "2012-09-13 23:00:1347548413"}')
```

Otherwise, MySQL will complain with a cryptic message, because it tries to interpret the raw JSON as SQL. When I try to execute your example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2fad) using my definition of table `mytable`, I see this error:

> Schema Creation Failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1: